# set notification alert

Tags: android

hi ia m new to android..
i have developed a programme to set notification onspecific time
but the problem is it shows notification only of date before october 2011
if i enter any date of november its not showing any notification..
seems strange but really stuck here....

main activity..

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // for using this you need to

    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2011);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 25);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 28);

    Intent alarmintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            AlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmintent.putExtra("title", "Title of our Notification");
    alarmintent.putExtra("note", "Description of our  Notification");


    int HELLO_ID = 1;
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            getApplicationContext(), HELLO_ID, alarmintent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | 
             Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
}
```

and the alarm reciever activity...

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String NotificationManager = null;
    private static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationManager manger = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                "Combi Note", System.currentTimeMillis());
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                NOTIFICATION_ID, new Intent(context, 
                  AlarmReceiver.class), 0);
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String title = extras.getString("title");

        String note = extras.getString("note");
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, note, title, contentIntent);
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    manger.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting an alarm for 5/5/2011, this date has passed so it is executed immediately.

When you receive a instance of `Calendar`, I think that the system automatically fills in the current date & time. So change **only** what you need to change (I.E if you want to send a notification in 5 days, change the day **only** in the calendar instance)

By the way, when clicking the notification it will, again, call your `BroadcastReceiver` and this time the intent **won't** have the extras you have put in it while in the activity. When clicking the notification, you should launch an activity - not a broadcast receiver.

Comment: cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11); cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2011); cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 25); cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18); cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 28); this isnt working ....

Comment: thnks @Jong for help but can u try it our on ur eclipse for todays date and gimme the code...

Comment: DO NOT call `cal.set` for fields that you don't need to change - if you want to do some testings, change ONLY the minute

Comment: ok @Jong suppose i want to set notification for date 1/1/2012 and time 00.00 Hrs as for new year how would i do it...

Comment: Like this: http://pastebin.com/f7JiKwbw But what I mean is, if you don't need to change any date/time - don't call `set`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
```

Expects a 0-based value. 11 is december.

Comment: thanks..should i give values for day,year,hour,minute stc also on 0 based start basis... plzz help

Comment: Only months are 0-based. When dealing whith months you'd better use constant values such as cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.OCTOBER); Please visit http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html for more details.

Comment: you should give numerical values as what they are, and use the constants for litteral values (months, days of week)